# How does `git rebase master` check a reapplying commit as a conflict?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Assume we have two example with its commits (`line 1, line 2...` is the content of a `foo` file, which is the only file in working directory):

Example 1:

```
line 1     line 1
line 2     line 22
line 3     line 3
  C0---------C1 [master]
   \
    C2 [test]
  line 1
  line 222
  line 3
```

Example 2:

```
line 1     line 1
line 2     line 22
line 3     line 3
  C0---------C1 [master]
   \
    C2--------C3 [test]
  line 1     line 1
  line 22    line 222
  line 3     line 3
```

I ran `git checkout test` and `git rebase master` on each of those examples, and I saw that Example 1 has a conflict, while Example 2 doesn't have any.

In Example 1, when reapplying `C2`, I guess Git do a 3-way merge on `C2`, `C1` and `C0`, which detect that `"line 222"` on `C2` different with `"line 22"` on `C1` and different with `"line 2"` on base (`C0`), so Git check that as a conflict.

In Example 2, the patch of `C2` is already has in `master` so Git skip it. But when reapplying `C3`, if Git does a 3-way merge on `C3`, `C1` and `C0`, which detect that `"line 222"` on `C3` different with `"line 22"` on `C1` and different with `"line 2"` on base (`C0`), then Git should check that as a conflict, but in real Git doesn't.

So in real, how does Git rebasing check a reapplying commit as a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each commit is copied by (or as if by) `git cherry-pick`.  A cherry-pick is a merge whose merge base is the parent of the commit being picked, with the `--ours` version being the `HEAD` commit and the `--theirs` version being the commit being picked. So, given:

```
C0--C1   <-- master
 \
  C2--C3   <-- test
```

and:

```
git checkout test && git rebase master
```

Git will first copy `C2` to `C2'`, then copy `C3` to `C3'`.

When copying `C2`, the merge base is `C0` (parent of `C2`), `--ours` is `C1` (tip of `master`), and `--theirs` is `C2` (being copied).  After the copy is finished we have this:

```
       C2'  <-- HEAD
      /
C0--C1   <-- master
 \
  C2--C3   <-- test
```

Next, Git cherry-picks `C3`.  The merge base is therefore `C2` (parent of `C3`), `--ours` is `C2'`, and `--theirs` is `C3`.

There is a merge conflict if the difference (`git diff`) from base to ours, vs the difference from base to theirs, touches "the same lines" of the same file.  "Same" in this case includes one line after the line touched.  So, compare the contents of `C2` (base) to each of `C2'` and `C3`, to see which lines changed in ours (`C2` vs `C2'`) and theirs (`C2` vs `C3`).  If we've taken "their" change to line 2 when producing `C2'`, the difference from `C2` to `C2'` is empty, and therefore the merge is trivially resolved by taking the file from `C3`.

Comment: It's very clearly for me now, I got it. Thank you very much.